# How to place images on top of table in html?

Tags: javascript, image

Here I'm developing snakes and ladder game.

First I have developed game board and placed numbers on that, but I don't know how to put snakes and ladder on some positions.

Could anybody guide me please?

```
function loadgameboard() {
var numbers = 64;
var tablestart = "<table id='contentTable' width='35%' background=''  height='74%' bgcolor='#EFE8BB' border=1>";
var tableend = "</table>";
var trstart = "<tr>";
var trend = "</tr>";
var tdstart = "<td align='middle' >";
var tdend = "</td>";
var fontsizeStart = "<font size='5'>";
var fontSizeEnd = "</font>";

var numberOfRowColumns = Math.sqrt(numbers);
document.write(tablestart);
for (var i = numberOfRowColumns; i > 0; i--) {
    document.write(trstart);
    for (var j = numberOfRowColumns; j > 0; j--) {
        document.write(tdstart);
        document.write(fontsizeStart);
        document.write(numbers);
        document.write(fontSizeEnd);
        document.write(tdend);
        numbers--;
    }
    document.write(trend);
}
document.write(tableend);
} 
window.onload = loadgameboard;
```

Suppose if I want to place one snake and one image, how can I do it?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: how about putting background image(whole image of snake and ladder).

Comment: Don't use `document.write` and `<font>`.

Comment: @vusan,background i have not put anything,just i need,one snake at number 28 to 14 and one ladder 5 to 18.how can i place images there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tdstart` variable should include an `id` field, such as: `var tdstart = "<td align='middle' id=";`  Don't set the id here, or close the tag yet.  In the loop where you create the table, do something like this: `document.write(tdstart+ "'"+i+j+"'>");` That gives every data-cell a unique ID and also closes the tag.  After that, at any time you like, you can set some other variable, perhaps one named `tcell` to any of the cells in the table: `tcell=document.getElementById('15');` where the `15` specifies a row and a column; if you have more than 10 of each, you might use letters of the alphabet instead of digits--just remember to assign letters instead of numbers `i` and `j` to the `id=` part of your main loop.  That could be done by

```
document.write(tdstart+ "'"+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".substr(i,1)+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".substr(j,1)+"'>");
```

Use more letters as needed, and remember lowercase is different from uppercase, you can handle a 52x52 table this way.

Once you have access to the cell, you can edit its content, such as

```
tcell.innerHTML="64"+"<img src='ladder.png' />"
```

The 64 is the original number you put in the cell, in your loop.  You can change the number, or put it after the image, or both.  And of course you can remove the image:  `tcell.innerHTML="64";`